# Android SMS context menu

Tags: java, android, sms, contextmenu

I have done a little but of looking around on google and think i know the answer to this before asking, however most of what i found on the internet dates back almost a year so.

Is it possible to add an extra menu item to the SMS context menu so for example an app i am working on, if you press it it can open you app from that message.

otherwise is it possible to add a "flag" to an SMS so then when it is recieved on a device it would try to open it in a different application than the stock SMS one if it exsists.

*edit to elaborate:

I am currently writing an app which is basically a custom SMS app (its a uni project) What i am trying to find out is if it is possible to 1 of 2 things:

1, add a context menu item to a SMS in the standard app - the idea of this menu is to link it to open it in my app

if not then

2, add somesort of flag? to the text message so that when its recived on the phone a service or something checks to see if the flag exists, if it does then opens that SMS on my app (if its installed) else opens it in the standard default SMS application

Comment: @Anup - hopefully that clears it up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second approach I will suggest you should use BroadcastReceiver.

BroadcastReceiver is used when there will any action which needs to happens on a particular

event let's say onIncomingVoiceCall or incomingSMS.

I think this will serve your purpose.

If you find my answer useful please mark it.

Best Regards,
~Anup